# Always present password field on Windows login instead of fingerprint

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, login, login-screen, fingerprint

I've recently enabled the fingerprint reader on my laptop running Windows 8.1 and now use it for login as a supplement to my password. When I login using my fingerprint, the default login method is changed to fingerprints, and Windows displays this when I turn on the computer:

[image: Login with fingerprint]

However, when I'm at home and my laptop is plugged into my docking station, I can't access the fingerprint reader underneath the laptop lid. Thus, I have to click *Sign-in options* and then the password icon before being able to type my password:

[image: Login with fingerprints, options folded out]
[image: Login with password, coming from fingerprints]

When the password field is shown, I can still login using my fingerprint, and thus, having the password field shown always would be ideal, so as to save clicks each time I log in a home. Is this possible?

Comment: I have used alternative methods of authenticating my users accounts for over 2 decades.  I have yet to date found a way to do what you want, for that reason, I simply do not believe what you want is possible.

Comment: If that's the case, it's too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Windows 10. The sing-in screen now always shows the password field, even if I last signed in with my fingerprint.